# asp.net core 1.1 antiforgery with angular 2/4

Tags: angular, security, .net-core

I am trying to implement antiforgery token on asp.net core 1.1 with angurl 2/4 cli but everytime when I use "ValidateAntiForgeryToken" system giving me 400 Bad request error.

in asp.net startup.cs I have use

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");



app.Use(async (context, next) =>{
 await next();
 string path = context.Request.Path.Value;
 if (path != null && !path.ToLower().Contains("/api"))
 {
      var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
      context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN",
       tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions{HttpOnly = false});
 }
    
 if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && 
     !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
 {
     context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
     context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
     await next();
 }
});
```

in angular app.module.ts I am using something like

```
provider:[{ provide: XSRFStrategy, useFactory: xsrfFactory}],

export function xsrfFactory() {
    return new CookieXSRFStrategy('*******', '********');
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this guide helpful? http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1343/aspnet-core-csrf-antiforgery-token

```
public class AngularAntiforgeryCookieResultFilter: ResultFilterAttribute
{
    private IAntiforgery antiforgery;
    public AngularAntiforgeryCookieResultFilter(IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
        this.antiforgery = antiforgery;
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is ViewResult)
        {
            var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context.HttpContext);
            context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
        }
    }
}

services.AddAntiforgery(opts => opts.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-Token");
services.AddMvc(opts =>
{
    opts.Filters.AddService(typeof(AngularAntiforgeryCookieResultFilter));
});
services.AddTransient< AngularAntiforgeryCookieResultFilter >();
```

Comment: I have tried this but I think my angular part is not configured properly as I have tried setting header "X-XSRF-Token" and still webapi giving me 400 error.

Comment: Can you try to make a test request with jQuery? Make sure server side works correctly.

Comment: I am sorry for late reply I have tried to make request thru jquery but still I am getting same error it seems like I haven't configured it properly..

Comment: Then you need to make the server side work right first.

Comment: so now my antiforgery is working only when I remove authorize

Comment: Please see 'Protecting controller actions' in the guide. It's not using authorize strategy.